# Spark on Yarn error : Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-shell

While starting `spark-shell --master yarn --deploy-mode client` I am getting error :

> Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or
>   unable to launch application master.

Here is the complete log from Yarn:

> 19/08/28 00:54:55 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8032
>
> Container: container_1566921956926_0010_01_000001 on
>   rhel7-cloudera-dev_33917
>   =============================================================================== LogType:stderr Log Upload Time:28-Aug-2019 00:46:31 LogLength:523 Log
>   Contents: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J:
>   Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/yarn/local/usercache/rhel/filecache/26/__spark_libs__5634501618166443611.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> LogType:stdout Log Upload Time:28-Aug-2019 00:46:31 LogLength:5597 Log
>   Contents: 2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal
>   handler for TERM 2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered
>   signal handler for HUP 2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SignalUtils:54 -
>   Registered signal handler for INT 2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO 
>   SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: yarn,rhel 2019-08-28
>   00:46:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: yarn,rhel
>   2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls
>   groups to:  2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing
>   modify acls groups to:  2019-08-28 00:46:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 -
>   SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users 
>   with view permissions: Set(yarn, rhel); groups with view permissions:
>   Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(yarn, rhel); groups with
>   modify permissions: Set() 2019-08-28 00:46:20 INFO 
>   ApplicationMaster:54 - Preparing Local resources 2019-08-28 00:46:21
>   INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - ApplicationAttemptId:
>   appattempt_1566921956926_0010_000001 2019-08-28 00:46:21 INFO 
>   ApplicationMaster:54 - Waiting for Spark driver to be reachable.
>   2019-08-28 00:46:21 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Driver now available:
>   rhel7-cloudera-dev:34872 2019-08-28 00:46:21 INFO 
>   TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to
>   rhel7-cloudera-dev/192.168.56.112:34872 after 107 ms (0 ms spent in
>   bootstraps) 2019-08-28 00:46:22 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - 
>   =============================================================================== YARN executor launch context:   env:
>       CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}{{PWD}}/**spark_conf**{{PWD}}/**spark_libs**/*$HADOOP_CONF_DIR$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*
>           $HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/*$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/lib/*$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/*$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/lib/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/lib/*$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/*$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/lib/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar{{PWD}}/**spark_conf**/**hadoop_conf**
>       SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH -> /etc/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar
>       SPARK_YARN_STAGING_DIR -> *********(redacted)
>       SPARK_USER -> *********(redacted)
>       SPARK_CONF_DIR -> /etc/spark/conf
>       SPARK_HOME -> /etc/spark
>
> command:
>       {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java \ 
>         -server \ 
>         -Xmx1024m \ 
>         -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp \ 
>         '-Dspark.driver.port=34872' \ 
>         -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir= \ 
>         -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' \ 
>         org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend \ 
>         --driver-url \ 
>         spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@rhel7-cloudera-dev:34872 \ 
>         --executor-id \ 
>          \ 
>         --hostname \ 
>          \ 
>         --cores \ 
>         1 \ 
>         --app-id \ 
>         application_1566921956926_0010 \ 
>         --user-class-path \ 
>         file:$PWD/**app**.jar \ 
>         1>/stdout \ 
>         2>/stderr
>
> resources:
>       **spark_libs** -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "rhel7-cloudera-dev" port: 9000 file:
>   "/user/rhel/.sparkStaging/application_1566921956926_0010/**spark_libs__5634501618166443611.zip"
>   } size: 232107209 timestamp: 1566933362350 type: ARCHIVE visibility:
>   PRIVATE
>       __spark_conf** -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "rhel7-cloudera-dev" port: 9000 file:
>   "/user/rhel/.sparkStaging/application_1566921956926_0010/**spark_conf**.zip"
>   } size: 208377 timestamp: 1566933365411 type: ARCHIVE visibility:
>   PRIVATE
>
> =============================================================================== 2019-08-28 00:46:22 INFO  RMProxy:98 - Connecting to ResourceManager
>   at /0.0.0.0:8030 2019-08-28 00:46:22 INFO  YarnRMClient:54 -
>   Registering the ApplicationMaster 2019-08-28 00:46:22 INFO 
>   YarnAllocator:54 - Will request 2 executor container(s), each with 1
>   core(s) and 1408 MB memory (including 384 MB of overhead) 2019-08-28
>   00:46:22 INFO  YarnAllocator:54 - Submitted 2 unlocalized container
>   requests. 2019-08-28 00:46:22 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 - Started
>   progress reporter thread with (heartbeat : 3000, initial allocation :
>   200) intervals 2019-08-28 00:46:22 ERROR ApplicationMaster:43 -
>   RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM 2019-08-28 00:46:23 INFO  ApplicationMaster:54 -
>   Final app status: UNDEFINED, exitCode: 16, (reason: Shutdown hook
>   called before final status was reported.) 2019-08-28 00:46:23 INFO 
>   ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
>
> Container: container_1566921956926_0010_02_000001 on
>   rhel7-cloudera-dev_33917
>   =============================================================================== LogType:stderr Log Upload Time:28-Aug-2019 00:46:31 LogLength:3576 Log
>   Contents: SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings. SLF4J:
>   Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/yarn/local/usercache/rhel/filecache/26/__spark_libs__5634501618166443611.zip/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.16.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: Found binding in
>   [jar:file:/etc/hadoop-2.6.0/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
>   SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an
>   explanation. SLF4J: Actual binding is of type
>   [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.IOException: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException;
>   Host Details : local host is: "rhel7-cloudera-dev/192.168.56.112";
>   destination host is: "rhel7-cloudera-dev":9000;   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:772)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1474)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1401)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:232)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:752)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1977)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1118)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$18.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1114)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:235)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$7$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:232)
>     at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)   at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$7.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:232)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$7.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:800)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:799)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.(ApplicationMaster.scala:197)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:823)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:854)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.waitForWork(Client.java:935)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:967)
>   Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException     ... 2 more
>
> LogType:stdout Log Upload Time:28-Aug-2019 00:46:31 LogLength:975 Log
>   Contents: 2019-08-28 00:46:26 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered signal
>   handler for TERM 2019-08-28 00:46:26 INFO  SignalUtils:54 - Registered
>   signal handler for HUP 2019-08-28 00:46:26 INFO  SignalUtils:54 -
>   Registered signal handler for INT 2019-08-28 00:46:27 INFO 
>   SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: yarn,rhel 2019-08-28
>   00:46:27 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: yarn,rhel
>   2019-08-28 00:46:27 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls
>   groups to:  2019-08-28 00:46:27 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing
>   modify acls groups to:  2019-08-28 00:46:27 INFO  SecurityManager:54 -
>   SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users 
>   with view permissions: Set(yarn, rhel); groups with view permissions:
>   Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(yarn, rhel); groups with
>   modify permissions: Set() 2019-08-28 00:46:28 INFO 
>   ApplicationMaster:54 - Preparing Local resources 2019-08-28 00:46:28
>   ERROR ApplicationMaster:43 - RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM

Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Comment: Not sure but, can you try manually cleaning `/user/rhel/.sparkStaging/` directory. Sometime if old application is not closed properly `System.exit(0)` then we see such error.